# Using Cauchy to prove that a recursive sequence is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of numbers in the interval $(0,1)$. The terms can be defined recursively by: $a_n < \dfrac{a_{n-1} + a_{n+1}}{2}$ when $n\geq 2$. Show this sequence is convergent.

I think we should use the Cauchy criterion... But I am having difficulty breaking down this recurrence relation to see what is happening to the distances between the terms.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Look at $b_k = a_k-a_{k-1}.$ Show that this sequence is increasing and thus it has a limit as $b_k$ are bounded. Then, it would be easy to use Cauchy.

Comment: I tried to prove it is Cauchy but it does not seem clear. Any hint please?

Answer (score 3):

$a_{n+1} - a_{n}$ is increasing, so that
$$
\begin{align}
 a_n &= a_m + (a_{m+1} - a_{m}) + \cdots + (a_{n} - a_{n-1}) \\
&\ge a_m + (n-m)(a_{m+1} - a_{m}) \tag{*}
\end{align} 
$$
for $n > m$. If $a_{m+1} > a_{m}$ for some $m$ then $(*)$ implies $a_n \to \infty$, contradicting the assumption that $(a_n)$ is bounded.

So $(a_n)$ is *decreasing.* It is also assumed to be bounded below, therefore convergent.

*Remark:* Inequality $(*)$ is the discrete analogue of the fact that the graph of a convex function lies above its tangent line at any point, i.e. that
$$
 f(y) \ge f(x) + (y-x)f'(x)
$$
for differentiable convex functions.