# A bounded sequence is convergent if each term is greater than the average of adjacent terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence such that

$x_n \geq \dfrac{x_{n-1}+x_{n+1}}{2}$ for all $n \geq 2$.

We need to show that $(x_n)$ is convergent.
I tried to show that the sequence is monotone then by the monotone convergence criterion, it must be convergent. Since it is recurrence inequality, I tried to solve it explicitly, but I couldn't. Am I in the right track?

Comment: @C-RAM, sir, I don't want the full answer, I just need a hint to start with. Thanks

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2461084/42969 (found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x_n%20%5Cgeq%20%5Cdfrac%7Bx_%7Bn-1%7D%2Bx_%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D%7B2%7D%24%2C%20AND%20content%3Abounded))

Comment: Here is a hint: Note that the inequality is a discrete analog of 'midpoint concavity'. So, you should expect that $n \mapsto x_n$ behaves like a concave function. This, together with boundedness of $(x_n)$, allows to draw rich conclusions regarding the behavior of $(x_n)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee: I see it now. But the link from my first comment is an exact duplicate.

Comment: @MartinR, I agree. The first link seems a duplicate, including the point that the answer therein only reveals hints and not a full answer.

Comment: @MartinR, I proved the convergence of $(b_n)$, but I couldn't use this to show that $(a_n)$ satisfies the Cauchy criterion and so it is convergent.

Comment: @Adam_math: I have added another answer to the duplicate target and hope it helps.

Comment: @MartinR. Thank you sir, this is really helpful.